# XSLT transformation using collection is missing context item

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I want to use XSLT to read all the XML files within a subdirectory and output the results to a single XML file, but I'm getting an error message that the context item is absent. The XSL works if it is applied to one file at a time, but I can't get it work when using the Collection function.

Here is the XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="inFile">
             <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates mode="inFile" select="node()|@*"/>
             </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="main" match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="inFile" select="collection('file:///C:/2011 Valid XML/XML?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')"/>
    <LookupTables>
        <Facility_Identifiers>
            <xsl:for-each select="/Report/RegistrationData/Facility/Identifiers/IdentifierList">
                <Facility_Identifier Org="{/Report/RegistrationData/Organisation/Details/BusinessLegalName}" Facility="{/Report/RegistrationData/Facility/Details/FacilityName}" NPRI_ID="{Identifier[IdentifierType = 'NationalPollutantReleaseInventoryId']/IdentifierValue}" GHGIS_ID="{Identifier[IdentifierType = 'GHGRPId']/IdentifierValue}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Facility_Identifiers>
        <NAICS_Details>
            <xsl:for-each select="/Report/RegistrationData/Facility/Identifiers/NAICSCodeList/NAICSCode">
                <NAICS_Detail Org="{/Report/RegistrationData/Organisation/Details/BusinessLegalName}" Facility="{/Report/RegistrationData/Facility/Details/FacilityName}" NAICS="{Code}" Classification="{NAICSClassification}" Percentage="{ActivityPercentage}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </NAICS_Details>
    </LookupTables>
</xsl:template>
```

The source XML files look like this:

```
<Report xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
    <RegistrationData>  
        <Facility>  
            <Details>  
                <FacilityName>Random Location</FacilityName>  
            </Details>  
            <Identifiers>  
                <IdentifierList>  
                    <Identifier>  
                        <IdentifierType>NationalPollutantReleaseInventoryId</IdentifierType>  
                        <IdentifierValue>N999</IdentifierValue>  
                    </Identifier>  
                    <Identifier>  
                        <IdentifierType>GHGRPId</IdentifierType>  
                        <IdentifierValue>G77777</IdentifierValue>  
                    </Identifier>  
                </IdentifierList>  
                <NAICSCodeList>  
                    <NAICSCode>  
                        <NAICSClassification>205</NAICSClassification>  
                        <Code>322121</Code>  
                        <ActivityPercentage>100.00</ActivityPercentage>  
                    </NAICSCode>  
                    <NAICSCode>  
                        <NAICSClassification>81</NAICSClassification>  
                        <Code>221112</Code>  
                        <ActivityPercentage>90.00</ActivityPercentage>  
                    </NAICSCode>  
                </NAICSCodeList>  
            </Identifiers>  
        </Facility>  
        <Organisation>  
            <Details>  
                <BusinessLegalName>The Corporation</BusinessLegalName>  
            </Details>  
        </Organisation>  
    </RegistrationData>  
</Report>
```

I want the target XML file to look like this:

```
<LookupTables>  
    <Facility_Identifiers>  
        <Facility_Identifier Org="The Corporation" Facility="Random Location" NPRI_ID="N999" GHGIS_ID="G77777"/>  
    </Facility_Identifiers>  
    <NAICS_Details>  
        <NAICS_Detail Org="The Corporation" Facility="Random Location" NAICS="322121" Classification="205" Percentage="100.00"/>  
        <NAICS_Detail Org="The Corporation" Facility="Random Location" NAICS="221112" Classification="81" Percentage="90.00"/>  
    </NAICS_Details>  
</LookupTables>
```

Comment: Please post the structure of the input documents and the structure of the result you want, currently all we know is that you want to pull in all files in a directory to create a single result file. But we don't know how you want to combine those files and which file(s) are supposed to populate the data in that `LookupTables` element where you use paths like `/Report/RegistrationData/Facility/Identifiers/IdentifierList`. Perhaps you want `collection('file:///C:/2011 Valid XML/XML?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')/Report/RegistrationData/Facility/Identifiers/IdentifierList` instead.

Comment: I've edited the original question to include the XSL, the source XML and the target XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compile the data from all files use an approach like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="input-dir" select="'file:///C:/2011 Valid XML/XML'"/>

<xsl:template name="main">
  <LookupTables>
        <xsl:variable name="input-docs"
          select="collection(iri-to-uri(concat($input-dir, '?select=*.xml')))"/>
        <Facility_Identifiers>
            <xsl:for-each select="$input-docs/Report/RegistrationData/Facility/Identifiers/IdentifierList">
                <Facility_Identifier Org="{ancestor::RegistrationData/Organisation/Details/BusinessLegalName}" 
                Facility="{ancestor::RegistrationData/Facility/Details/FacilityName}" 
                NPRI_ID="{Identifier[IdentifierType = 'NationalPollutantReleaseInventoryId']/IdentifierValue}" GHGIS_ID="{Identifier[IdentifierType = 'GHGRPId']/IdentifierValue}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Facility_Identifiers>
        <NAICS_Details>
            <xsl:for-each select="$input-docs/Report/RegistrationData/Facility/Identifiers/NAICSCodeList/NAICSCode">
                <NAICS_Detail Org="{ancestor::RegistrationData/Organisation/Details/BusinessLegalName}" 
                Facility="{ancestor::RegistrationData/Facility/Details/FacilityName}" NAICS="{Code}" 
                Classification="{NAICSClassification}" Percentage="{ActivityPercentage}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </NAICS_Details>  </LookupTables>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```